# Applying custom font in css is not working?

Tags: css

I am trying to use a custom font for the headings on my site but I cannot get it to work. It is just displaying as default Times New Roman or something no matter what I try. Does anyone have any advice about what I can do to get this font to show?

```
<style>

@font-face {
font-family:"volcano";
src: url("/wp-content/themes/wp-bootstrap-4/assets/fonts/Volcano-King.ttf") format ("truetype"),
     url("/wp-content/themes/wp-bootstrap-4/assets/fonts/Volcano-King.woff") format ("woff");
}

h1 {
font-family: "volcano";
}

</style>
```

Comment: Have you confirmed via devtools that the paths are correct and the fonts are loading?

Comment: I have inspected the element in question and looked at the source but the font does not appear to be loading. It gets as far as the assets folder but then no further. It doesn't seem to be able to see the fonts folder. I have no idea why.

Comment: Can you try changing your URLs to ' ../fonts/Volcano-King.ttf '. Also double check your fonts are named with capital letters (may be volcano-king.ttf).

Comment: @maestroveale and you've confirmed the fonts folder and font files exist on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's a missing **:**

Try this

```
<style>

@font-face {
font-family:"volcano";
src: url("/wp-content/themes/wp-bootstrap-4/assets/fonts/Volcano-King.ttf" format ("truetype"),
     url("/wp-content/themes/wp-bootstrap-4/assets/fonts/Volcano-King.woff" format ("woff");
}

h1 {
font-family: "volcano";
}

</style>
```

Comment: Hi, sorry but that doesn't work either. The colon isn't missing in my actual code - I just accidentally missed out when writing my question!

Answer (score 0):

```
h1 {
font-family: "volcano";
}
```

add a colon between property-name and property-value

Comment: Hi, sorry but that doesn't work either. The colon isn't missing in my actual code - I just accidentally missed out when writing my question!

Comment: The url in the CSS needs to have the entire absolute URL, including the http part. Because stylesheet paths are relative to the stylesheet they are in, if they are in a file of their own, a partial path will work. But if the style is not in its own file, the path will be relative to the dynamically-generated page address, so it needs to have the absolute full path.

Comment: I have amended the URL to https://readingrampage.org.uk/home/rampagesdsa/public_html/wp-content/themes/wp-bootstrap-4/assets/fonts/Volcano-King.tff with https:// and unfortunately it's still made no difference.

Comment: have you enqueue the style in functions.php or added it to style.css?

Comment: Added to style.css

Comment: i m not sure but try changing path with just url("/fonts/you-font-name" format ("your-format"))

Comment: Nope, that didn't work either. Thank you for continued help, though!

Comment: i can see that you added some font-family using path like. url("../fonts/font-name") . is it not working when you do in this case ?

Comment: remove 'home/rampagesdsa/public_html/' from your URL in this instance...